# Embedded Image not Adding to Stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sprite-sheet

So I have an image that I'm trying to embed to use as a sprite sheet. My problem is that I am receiving no errors at all, but my image can't even be added to the stage. It's like nothing is being loaded at all.

I am using the Flash CS 5.5 compiler. Here is my code:

```
public class Game extends MovieClip {
    [Embed(source='../assets/images/sprite_sheet_1.png')]
    private var sheetClass:Class;
    private var sheet:Bitmap = new sheetClass();

    public function Game() {
        addChild (sheet);
    }
}
```

I've also tried fiddling with the x and y values to make sure nothing is just covering it up and I can't see any problems with that, either. It's just not showing up.
I don't understand why it's not working as intended. Any aid would be fantastic. Thanks!

P.S. - I'm trying to embed the sprite sheet because someone recommended it would be a better route than just using URLLoaders, but is that necessarily true? Is it just true because we are talking about sprite sheets for a smallish Flash game?

Comment: And when you open a sprite_sheet_1.png with some external viewer , is it ok ?

Comment: Yes. The image opens up fine anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check a checkbox called something like "Export SWC" under the publish settings. I'm not sure of the exact phrasing because I don't have the same version of Flash that you have.

See [this page](http://knowledge.robotlegs.org/discussions/problems/523-using-robotlegs-in-flash-cs55) and [this page](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4287163)

Comment: I tried checking the SWC box under Publish in the Publish Settings, but nothing seems to have changed. Is there something else I need to do? I checked out the pages and they don't seem to indicate anything else besides checking SWC.

Comment: @Lapys I'm not sure, I usually use the Flex compiler rather than the IDE.

Comment: I'm honestly not even sure how to get Flex to work. I tried downloading the Flex SDK but it seems to be a really overly complicated way of doing things, and through XML. I don't even quite understand where you begin to write code.

EDIT: I suppose you'd just use FlashDevelop. But why is it that this won't work in the IDE?

Comment: @Lapys I have a few suggestions: Try creating a new project and try embedding the image in the new project. Just to make sure that it isn't some other code in your current project that is causing the image to not appear. You could also try embedding the image in a new project in Flashdevelop to see if it works there. Also, try embedding a different image/image type to see if the problem is with your image file.

Comment: Okay, trying it in FlashDevelop actually worked! The image seems to have embedded fine, and it added to the stage. Shouldn't be any problem with working with it now.
P.S. Is there any way to take the UI, buttons, etc over to FlashDevelop from Flash IDE CS 5.5?

Comment: Yes, in the same way , with `embed`

Comment: @Lapys Are the ui/buttons drawn inside flash, or are they external graphics?

Comment: @Lapys [this page](http://www.dafishinsea.com/blog/2009/08/19/how-to-get-flash-ide-assets-into-actionscript-or-flex-projects/) might help.

Comment: They're inside of flash. I suppose I could export them, though. Just wouldn't know exactly how to go from there since obviously Flash takes care of it for you. Thanks for the link, though. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @Lapys I just thought of something. If you are using the Flash IDE and you want to include an asset in your swf, why not just add it to the Library?

Comment: I honestly didn't know I could do that. I did, however, try FlashDevelop and tried importing the UI as a .SWC file and making a class of it, and it worked like a dream. No hassle whatsoever. That being said, do you think it wise for me to try and hack it with Flash, or go on to FlashDevelop? It seems like a lot of people prefer the latter around here. Why is that?

Comment: @Lapys I like FlashDevelop because it's free, and to me it just seems cleaner, because I mainly work with code-generated graphics/animations. If I was doing animations more suited towards the timeline (using lots of custom art) or needed to do a lot of asset creation inside the IDE I'd use that.

Comment: Ah, I suppose that one didn't. But pointing me in the right direction definitely gets my thanks. I'll up the relevant comments instead. Thanks again!